# Upload File as String to JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload

Is there any way for a client to upload a file in an HTML form (e.g. .txt or .csv formats) to a JavaScript variable as a string using only JavaScript?  If so, could you provide a simple example?  I don't want to use any PHP.

Comment: Have a look at the FileReader API

Comment: Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: ahh i noticed no php! well, with only JS it is not possible! because it is client side scripting not server side ;)

Comment: It is possible, once again with the FileReader API, it is a javascript only api !

Comment: @wagtail It has nothing to do with Jquery it is an issue which Javascript version do you want to use. The last one supports this api. Javascript 1.5 or older doesn't support that.

Comment: oh thanks @yent, well i didn;t know about it! i should have been writing a 300 lines code of both js and php if you should not have told us about it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example based on a form named "myform" that contains a file input named "myfile" :

```
document.forms['myform'].elements['myfile'].onchange = function(evt) {
    if(!window.FileReader) return; // Browser is not compatible

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        if(evt.target.readyState != 2) return;
        if(evt.target.error) {
            alert('Error while reading file');
            return;
        }

        filecontent = evt.target.result;

        document.forms['myform'].elements['text'].value = evt.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsText(evt.target.files[0]);
};
```

Here's the associated HTML form:

```
<form id="myform">
  <p>
    <input id="myfile" name="files[]" multiple="" type="file" />
    <textarea id="text" rows="20" cols="40">nothing loaded</textarea>
  </p>
</form>
```

and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgepw79u/) to demo it.

Answer (score 8):

This variation on [yent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155310/upload-file-as-string-to-javascript-variable/14155586#14155586) manages multiple uploads and uses jquery:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
  <p>
    <input id="myfile" name="files[]" multiple="" type="file" />
    <textarea id="text" rows="20" cols="40">nothing loaded</textarea>
  </p>
</form>
```

script:

```
$("#myfile").on("change", function (changeEvent) {
  for (var i = 0; i < changeEvent.target.files.length; ++i) {
    (function (file) {               // Wrap current file in a closure.
      var loader = new FileReader();
      loader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
        if (loadEvent.target.readyState != 2)
          return;
        if (loadEvent.target.error) {
          alert("Error while reading file " + file.name + ": " + loadEvent.target.error);
          return;
        }
        console.log(loadEvent.target.result.length); // Your text is in loadEvent.target.result
      };
      loader.readAsText(file);
    })(changeEvent.target.files[i]);
  }
});
```

Worth noting:

- You must use one FileReader for each (concurrent) file read. Otherwise you see an exception like `The object is already busy reading`.
- The loadEvent callbacks will be called in an arbitrary order, likely dependent on the size of the upload.
- The loadEvent closure will see the `i` value which ended the loop.
- FileReader results are NOT arrays; they have no forEach.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8375hbnq/) demo preserves upload order by laying out divs in the change handler.